# Lazy load not working for one of my custom module in Sparatcus 3.x but working for others

Tags: spartacus-storefront

first two modules are working fine with lazy loading but not the third one (productDetail)

[image]

getting the below error when trying to land on the screen, please help

[image]

Comment: Can you please share any one your custom module with config, like ProductDetailModule.ts file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replacing **StorefrontModule.config()** with **ConfigModule.withConfig()** inside the lazily loaded module worked for me